# Can I select multiple cells or a set of ranges in order to style them?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I know I can [access a range of cells in order to format them](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#formatting-cells):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B3:B7')->getFill()
    ->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)
    ->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF0000');
```

Now is there a way, and if yes, how can I define multiple cells or a set of ranges within the `getStyle()` call? I tried

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B3:B7;C6:C12')->getFill()->...
```

and

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B3;C9;D2;E6')->getFill()->...
```

but both didn't work and threw an error.

Comment: Unclear what you're actually trying to do, or what you expect to be returned

Comment: Instead of just formatting the range from `B3:B7`, I would like to format two ranges, `B3:B7` and `C6:C12`. Or I want to format multiple cells with one call, e.g. `B3;C9;D2;E6`.

Comment: Afraid that doesn't work, only one range at a time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Mark Baker (Coordinator of the PHPOffice suite of Open Source libraries)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker),

> that doesn't work, [you can] only [define] one range at a time.

Source: Comments above.